# File System Watcher OnChanged and OnCreated event gets called multiple times for a single file.

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, filesystemwatcher

Here is my code:

```
m_Watcher.Filter = "*.*";
                    m_Watcher.Path = settings.FolderName;
                    m_Watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
                    m_Watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
                    m_Watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
                    m_Watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
                    //m_Watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
                    m_Watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
                    m_Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Whenever I am copying a file or a folder to the folder being watched the OnCreated and OnChanged method gets fired multiple times. Can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong ?

Comment: When I was messing around with the FileSystemWatcher years ago it was working very poorly. I ended up using a Windows Service which would watch the directory by seeing if there were files in there, and then moving them out after a couple of minutes of no writes.

Comment: It is always an issue that the file may still be being written to, a copied file say an ISO of 3gb, isnt going to instantly appear, however windows will often allocate 3gb to it and spend the next 20 minutes contemplating that and then finally write to it if not using command line. Any file dump and grab idea has to wait to be sure all the data was written - a common way to do it is to dump a file after all files have copied over. Crude but effective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your event handlers, check the ChangeType property of the event raised. There are a number of different change types and several can be called, depending on what's happened in the file system.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6xf43e0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You may only wish to handle certain change types. So, it's just a matter of ensuring that there's logic in there to only handle the required change types you wish to manage. You may not need to handle so many of the events you've specified so far.

Comment: And make sure that the code that adds the above event handlers only gets called once, otherwise you'll get multiple events raised to the same handlers.